# Cross browser addons

Tags: firefox-addon, google-chrome-extension, internet-explorer-9

This has been discussed in a few threads - but none gave any real answers.
I need to develop a very simple browser addon which just has a single button, and can run a javascript function when pressed. It must sit as a toolbar or similair.

Now, is there an easy way to develop once for Chrome, IE, and FF?
Only supporting the latest version of each browser is fine too.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean a javascript (not particular to a certain browser e.g showing the history) you can run it like this (pasting it into the url bar):

`javascript:alert("Hello!");`

You can make a link with the href going to your script, then tell your users to drag the link into their bookmarks bar.  E.g

`<a href="javascript:alert('Hello!');">Link text</a>`

Comment: You sir, rock. I can't believe I didn't think of that.